# C# stream reader ReadToEnd() missing last character

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am trying to decrypt a string in C# using AES:

```
public static string AesDecrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    string plaintext = null;

    // Create an Aes object with the specified key and IV
    using Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create();
    aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    aesAlg.Key = Key;
    aesAlg.IV = IV;

    // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

    // Create the streams used for decryption
    using MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText);
    using CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    using StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt);

    // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream and place them in a string
    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
    return plaintext;
}
```

The encoded data is JSON, but when I decrypt it, I get all the right data except that the closing `}` of the JSON content is missing.

I think that the AES itself is not my problem here. I have doubts in the

```
plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
```

since only the last character is missing.

I don't know if I am supposed to flush any of the streams explicitly, but in any case it's a very curious problem.

Here's the full code for the encryption:

```
public static string AesEncrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    // Create an Aes object with the specified key and IV
    using Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create();
    aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    aesAlg.Key = Key;
    aesAlg.IV = IV;

    // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

    // Create the streams used for encryption
    using MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
    using CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    using StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt);

    // Write all data to the stream
    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
    swEncrypt.Flush();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
}
```

And this is how I call the decryption method:

```
public static AuthenticationData ParseAuthenticationToken(string token)
{
    byte[] tokenBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(token);
    string json = AesEncryption.AesDecrypt(tokenBytes, aes.Key, aes.IV);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticationData>(json);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that character is included in `cipherText`?

Comment: I think it's very unlikely to be a `StreamReader` problem. If you read a single character at a time, do you see the final character? What's encrypting the data?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've included the encryption code in my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in your encryption code. Although you're calling `seEncrypt.Flush()`, you're not calling `csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock()`. That automatically happens when the stream is disposed, but you're not doing that until after you've called `msEncrypt.ToArray()`. I would rewrite that code as:

```cs
MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    using StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt);
    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
    // swEncrypt is disposed here, flushing it. Then csEncrypt is disposed,
    // flushing the final block.
}
return msEncrypt.ToArray();
```